# how to get the value the auto complete in the form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I try to get the value of autocomplete in console.log()

it's posible to get the value of autocomplete after selection of title ?

find below code source

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tewwbp?file=demo.js
[code source[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using uncontrolled Autocomplete so you don't have access to the value that is currently selected. To console the value you can use something like this:

```
<Autocomplete    
onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        console.log(newValue);
     // setValue(newValue);
    }}
...
/>
```

Comment: could you plase update my code source ? im beginner with react

Comment: I have done changes on your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tewwbp-4ppff3?file=demo.js

Comment: @MehdiFrid To encourage people answering on stackoverflow, you should upvote and accept the answers if it provides solution to your problem. This way another user who is looking at the question can identify which answer is working.